# Move a CSS sprite within a div?

Tags: css, css-sprites

What I'm trying to do is have a sprite as a background for my links.  Then when it hovers it changes to a different colored sprite.  The code below accomplished that.

The problem is that the sprites are directly over/behind the link text.  Is there a way to position where the sprite is shown in relation to the text?

If I change `background-position` it just changes which pixels are used for the sprite, not the actual position of the sprite.  Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<a class="sprite-link" href="#">Link Text</a>
```

CSS

```
a:hover {
color: black;
}

.sprite-link {
background: url(spriteurl.png) no-repeat;
background-position: 0px 0px;
width: 165px;
height: 45px;
display: block;
}

.sprite-link:hover {
background: url(spriteurl.png) no-repeat;
background-position: 0px -45px;
width: 165px;
height: 45px;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `padding-left` to separate the text from the background.

Comment: 'padding-left' on what element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `::after` pseudo-element to achieve that...

Check the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cPVUx/)**.

I don't have the sprite, but imagine that the square in the example is it.

**CSS**

```
.sprite-link::after {
    content: "";
    padding: 10px;
    background: red;
    width: 165px;
    height: 45px;
    display: block;
}

.sprite-link:hover::after {
    width: 165px;
    height: 45px;
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: Ok but how do I move the position of the square, relative to the link?

Comment: Sure! You can use position relative/absolute to "control" the pseudoelement. Put the relative position to the link and the absolute position to the pseudoelement. Then use top, right, bottom and left properties to move the square (pseudoelement).

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is use a separate span inside the a tag, and put the background on that.

HTML

```
<a class="sprite-link">
    <span></span>
    Link Text
</a>
```

CSS

```
a:hover {
    color: black;
}

.sprite-link > span {
    background: url(spriteurl.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    width: 165px;
    height: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.sprite-link:hover > span {
    background: url(spriteurl.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px -45px;
}
```

Comment: Same question as above... do I then use absolute/relative positioning on the span?

Comment: Yes, you would mark the a tag as `relative` and then mark the span as `absolute` (which means its absolute with respect to the a tag. The trouble with this is, you lose the flow layout the browser provides for you, and have to start doing all the layout manually. I would try to use margin, padding and align to control things. If you have an example /image of what you want to end up I can tweak the above for you

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolutely positioned pseudo element and put the sprite inside the pseudo element.

For instance (see fiddle):

```
a { position: relative; padding-right: 30px; display: inline-block;}
a:before { content:""; border: 1px solid #000; display: inline-block; position: absolute; width: 20px; height: 20px; right:0; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XJZfC/